как дать боту понять в каком чате пишет сообщение пользователь. aiogram
хэндлер ловит сообщение, но дает неправильный вариант ответа. допускаю, что ошибся в логике, но в упор не вижу. по идее, получая команду /ban бот проверяет, является ли чат -  группой, если да, до баним юзера и удаляем наше сообщение, если нет, то отправляем сообщение о том, что мы пишем в приватном чате.
код ниже
@router3.message(Command("ban"))
async def ban_user(message: Message):
    if message.chat.type == 'group':
        if not message.reply_to_message:
            await message.reply('This command needs to be as a reply to message')
            return
        await message.delete()
        await message.bot.ban_chat_member(chat_id=message.chat.id, user_id=message.reply_to_message.from_user.id,
                                          until_date=timedelta(seconds=29))

        return await message.reply_to_message.reply('User has been banned')
    else:
        await message.answer("it's private chat")


То есть, под словами неправильный вариант ответа, вы имеете ввиду, it's private chat?

Сейчас есть 4 типа чатов в телеграме: group, supergroup, channel и private. Скорее всего, вы проводили проверку в супергруппе, поэтому результат отрицательный. Условие стоит переписать так:
if message.chat.type in ('group', 'supergroup'):

